# How do I get the name of an image resource in a PictureBox?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms

I'm working on a game, it has a placing system and it's almost done, im trying to make a saving system using My.Settings, here is the code i have so far

```
Private Sub Menu_Save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Menu_Save.Click
    Dg_1 = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to save? This will overwrite your previous save.", "Warning!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
    If (Dg_1) = DialogResult.Yes Then
        If (Generated = 0) Then
            Tb_Chat.Text += Environment.NewLine
            Tb_Chat.Text += "Cannot save a blank world"
        ElseIf Generated = 1 Then
            My.Settings.savslot1_isused = True
            My.Settings.savslot1_hearts = Hp
            My.Settings.savslot1_hunger = Hunger
            My.Settings.stg_slot01 = Pb_BlockSpace001.Image
            My.Settings.stg_slot02 = Pb_BlockSpace002.Image
            My.Settings.stg_slot03 = Pb_BlockSpace003.Image
            My.Settings.stg_slot04 = Pb_BlockSpace004.Image
            My.Settings.stg_slot05 = Pb_BlockSpace005.Image
            Tb_Chat.Text += Environment.NewLine
            Tb_Chat.Text += "World Saved. " + TimeOfDay + "."
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

(I only saved 5 blocks to test it)

So then it comes up with an error saying:

Value of type 'Image' cannot be converted to 'String'

How can I make it so that it gets the name of the Resource instead of trying to convert an image into a string???

Comment: I am pretty sure that when you do something like…`string ImagePath = @"D:\mypath\someimage.jpg";` …`Image img = Image.FromFile(ImagePath);` … then … the `ImagePath` of the `Image` is NOT retained in the `Image` object itself. That path is lost unless you retain it somehow. A guess is to possibly save the `ImagePath` into the `img.Tag` property. However, I am guessing there is chance the `Tag` may get cleared and then you would have to maintain this “image to string path” in some other way. I am guessing this is what you are asking.

Comment: You mentioned `image resource`, does this mean images are stored in the project resources or from loading images from disk?

Comment: Its located in My.Resources

Comment: What i want it to do is get the name of the Resource from My.Resources (it saves the Resource name of the picture boxes Image)

Comment: “Where” the image is saved is irrelevant. The “path” to the image is lost after the image is loaded into the `Image` object. As I previously commented… you “could” save the path in the `Image.Tag` property or some other way… Point being… “your code” is going to have to “save” this image path info somehow. The `Image` object itself isn’t going to know anything about “where” it came from… nor should it.

Answer (score 0):

Since BitMap images are in My.Resources consider the follow.

First as mentioned, you can set the image name in the Tag property of the PictureBox and retrieve it when needed, or use a custom `PictureBox` with a property (change the name if so desired) ResourceName which will store the resource name.

```
Public Class ImageBox
    Inherits PictureBox
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Name of resource in projects Resources
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    Public Property ResourceName() As String
    
End Class
```

Create `ImageResourceHelper.vb` and add the following

```
Namespace My
    <ComponentModel.EditorBrowsable(ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Never)>
    Partial Friend Class _MyImages

        Private ReadOnly MyProperties As Reflection.PropertyInfo()
        Private ReadOnly MyBitmapNames As List(Of String)
        Public BitMapImages As new Dictionary(Of String, Bitmap)

        Public ReadOnly Property HasImages() As Boolean
        get
            Return BitMapImages.Count >0
        End Get
        End Property

        Private Sub GetBitMapImages()

            'BitMapImages = New Dictionary(Of String, Bitmap)

            Dim propertyInfo As Reflection.PropertyInfo() =
                GetType(Resources.Resources).GetProperties(Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or
                                                              Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or
                                                              Reflection.BindingFlags.Static)

            Dim BitMaps = (From T In propertyInfo Where T.PropertyType Is GetType(Bitmap)).ToList

            If BitMaps.Count > 0 Then
                For Each pInfo As Reflection.PropertyInfo In BitMaps

                    BitMapImages.Add(
                        pInfo.Name.Replace("_", " "),
                        CType(Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(pInfo.Name), Bitmap)
                    )

                Next
            End If

        End Sub
        Public Function BitmapFromResource(sender As String) As Bitmap

            Dim Item = (
                    From propertyInfo In MyProperties
                    Where propertyInfo.PropertyType Is GetType(Bitmap) AndAlso propertyInfo.Name = sender
                    ).FirstOrDefault

            If Item IsNot Nothing Then
                Return CType(Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(Item.Name), Bitmap)
            Else
                Dim bm As New Bitmap(256, 256)
                Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm)
                gr.Clear(Color.Transparent)

                Return bm

            End If

        End Function
        Public ReadOnly Property BitmapNames As List(Of String)
            Get
                Return MyBitmapNames
            End Get
        End Property
        Public Sub New()

            MyProperties = GetType(Resources.Resources).
                GetProperties(
                    Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or
                    Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or
                    Reflection.BindingFlags.Static)

            MyBitmapNames = (
                From propertyInfo In MyProperties
                Where propertyInfo.PropertyType Is GetType(Bitmap)
                Select propertyInfo.Name
                ).ToList

            GetBitMapImages()

        End Sub
    End Class
    <HideModuleName()>
    Friend Module Resource_Images
        Private ReadOnly instance As New ThreadSafeObjectProvider(Of _MyImages)
        ReadOnly Property Images() As _MyImages
            Get
                Return instance.GetInstance()
            End Get
        End Property
    End Module
End Namespace
```

**Form designer**

- Add a button to set the image (can also be done on selection change of the ListBox or Position changed event of the BindingSource.
- Add another button to get the current resource name.
- Add a ListBox
- Add the custom PictureBox

**My.Settings**

Add a new setting named `SelectedImageName` as String.

**Form code**

The following code load the ListBox with resource names, determines if `SelectedImageName` is set, if so set the PictureBox image a resource name and if not set select the first image from resources.

**On Form Closing event**
If an image is set via checking the PictureBox ResourceName property, set `SelectedImageName` which will be picked up in Form Shown event if the resource still exists.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1

    Private ReadOnly ImageBindingSource As New BindingSource

    Private Sub SetImageButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SetImageButton.Click

        If ListBox1.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim current = CType(ListBox1.SelectedItem, KeyValuePair(Of String, Bitmap))

        PictureBox1.Image = current.Value
        PictureBox1.ResourceName = current.Key

    End Sub
    Private Sub GetImageNameButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GetImageNameButton.Click
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PictureBox1.ResourceName) Then
            MessageBox.Show(PictureBox1.ResourceName)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Set an image and try again")
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown

        ImageBindingSource.DataSource = My.Images.BitMapImages

        ListBox1.DataSource = ImageBindingSource
        ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Key"
        ListBox1.ValueMember = "Value"

        If My.Images.HasImages Then
            If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(My.Settings.SelectedImageName) Then
                If My.Images.BitMapImages.ContainsKey(My.Settings.SelectedImageName) Then
                    PictureBox1.Image = My.Images.BitMapImages(My.Settings.SelectedImageName)
                    PictureBox1.ResourceName = My.Settings.SelectedImageName
                    ListBox1.SelectedIndex = ListBox1.FindString(My.Settings.SelectedImageName)
                Else
                    PictureBox1.Image = My.Images.BitMapImages.First().Value
                    PictureBox1.ResourceName = My.Images.BitMapImages.First().Key
                End If
            End If
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PictureBox1.ResourceName) Then
            My.Settings.SelectedImageName = CType(ListBox1.SelectedItem, KeyValuePair(Of String, Bitmap)).Key
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Of course this is for one PictureBox, repeat for each PictureBox. Also, if one or more resources are say icons the code to retrieve images will need to be adjusted accordingly. BitmapFromResource method can also be used to get an image from resources by name and if not found returns an empty image.